# PostMessage not working on Win8 or Win7, 64-bit

Tags: windows-8, windows-7-x64, postmessage

I have a C++ application that works on Win7, 32-bit.  But when it is run on either Win8 or Win7, 64-bit, it dies at a PostMessage call.  Is there a known anamoly with PostMessage?  Is there a work-around or alternative solution?

Thanks

Comment: did you check the Application eventlog for any information and about the event.

Comment: Sorry...I don't know how to do that.

Comment: OK--It has an "exception code" of 0xc0000005, which generally means a null pointer.  I simply return to my question, does PostMessage work differently under the different operation systems?

Comment: Any API, if used incorrectly, may work differently on different operating systems.  Without more information about the code that is failing, there isn't much we can say.

Comment: OK--well, that turned out to be a red herring.  Thanks, anyway.